# How to set a texture on a Object3D child Mesh

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I imported my Object3D like this:

```
var globalObject; // this is a global object

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('path/to/object3d.json', function(object) {
    globalObject = object;
    scene.add(globalObject);
});
```

What I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on a button, that certain Mesh elements of the whole object get a texture. I do it like this:

```
// on button click {
    for(var i in globalObject.children) {
        // apply to Mesh of interest {
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('path/to/image.jpg');
            globalObject.children[i].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture, needsUpdate: true});
        } // end apply to Mesh of interest
    }
} // end on button click
```

The above code seems to work so far as setting the texture. The problem here is that the texture looks kind of distorted. It looks like this http://db.tt/S5VEsByd

How to correct this, so that the full texture gets applied to both surfaces?

Comment: It looks like your object's texture coordinates are not set correctly. Where did you get the objects? If you can, check the object's texture coordinates in Blender or the software you used to create them.

Comment: yeah, I thought that something like that is possible. I actually am not a 3d designer and I got my object from a designer. Is there a way to reset texture coordinates from three.js to some default values or can those coords only be checked in a software that was used to create the object?

Comment: Well, there is not a way i am currently aware of. You will have to do this on your own. Check this answer here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2065#issuecomment-6352320
It generates planar mapping for all faces in X/Y-Plane. You would ahve to do this based on faceDirection to get some automatic unwrapping. Where did you get the obj from, do you only need this 1 obj to be correct?  You can also try to rebuild the obj with standard geometry from three.js that has correct texture coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
// on button click {
    for(var i in globalObject.children) {
        // apply to Mesh of interest {
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('path/to/image.jpg');
            texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            globalObject.children[i].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture, needsUpdate: true});
        } // end apply to Mesh of interest
    }
} // end on button click
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. What has an effect on how the texture is applied to a Mesh? Is is possible that a setting from my object file is interfering here? One more pic on how the texture should look like (the cube in the back) and how it looks on my objects (table like structure in the front): http://db.tt/j3M5Tghe

Comment: Make sure the texture is [power of 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two).